# Specified interface not declared - class method for derived object

Tags: fortran, intel-fortran

I'm trying to implement a framework for integrating ODE's in Fortran 2003. The idea is to have an abstract class odeType and a few subroutines for time integration, i/o, etc. Specific ODE's would then be implemented in objects derived from the base odeType. The example below yields an error when compiled with ifortran compiler on Linux:

```
error #8169: The specified interface is not declared.   [MSDDDERIVS_]
            procedure :: derivs => msdDderivs_
```

However, I don't seem to be able to declare a separate interface for this method aside from the abstract one implemented for derivs_ode already. If anyone has an idea what's wrong, I'd very much welcome your input!

```
module eomModule

implicit none

integer, parameter :: nDof=2

! ==========================
! ODE BASE CLASS DECLARATION
! ==========================
type, abstract :: odeType
    ! --- properties ---

    ! --- member function declarations ---
    contains
        ! calculation of the derivative vector
        ! NOTE: in C++ this would be a pure virtual function, redefine in each
        !   extended object to implement required dynamics.
        procedure(derivs_ode), deferred :: derivs

end type odeType

! define an interface for the abstract method to allow inheritance and overloading
! in derived types.
abstract interface
    subroutine derivs_ode(this, yDotNew, y, x)
        ! need to import custom type definitions from the outside scope
        import odeType, nDof

        ! declare arguments for the derived functions
        class(odeType), intent(in) :: this
        real*16, dimension(nDof*2), intent(out) :: yDotNew
        real*16, dimension(nDof*2), intent(in) :: y
        real*16, intent(in) :: x
    end subroutine
end interface

! ==========================
! MSD CLASS DECLARATION
! ==========================
type, extends(odeType) :: msdType
    ! --- properties ---
    real*16, dimension(nDof,nDof) :: m, k, c
    real*16, dimension(nDof) :: F, omega

    ! --- member function declarations ---
    contains
        ! calculation of the derivative vector

**!!!!    PROBLEMS HERE       !!!!!**
        procedure :: derivs => msdDderivs_

end type msdType

contains

!>
!! Computes derivatives of the state vector of a 2D mass-spring-damper system
!<
!=====================================================================
subroutine msdDerivs_(this, yDotNew, y, x)
!=====================================================================
    class(odeType), intent(in) :: this

    real*16, dimension(nDof*2), intent(out) :: yDotNew
    real*16, dimension(nDof*2), intent(in) :: y
    real*16, intent(in) :: x

    real*16, dimension(nDof,nDof) :: mInv
    real*16, dimension(nDof) :: effK, effC, effF

    integer :: i

    ! DO CALCULATIONS HERE
    ! return the updated derivative of the state vector
    yDotNew = (/0., 0., 0., 0./)

end subroutine msdDerivs_

end module eomModule

! =====================
program integrationTest

use eomModule

implicit none

! =====================
! --- define all program variables ---
real*16, dimension(nDof*2) :: y0
real*16 :: dt=1e-3, tEnd=10.0, t=0.

real*16, parameter :: PI=3.1415926359

type(msdType) :: msdOde

! --- populate system constants ---
msdOde%m(1,:) = (/0.2, 0.0/)
msdOde%m(2,:) = (/0.0, 0.2/)

msdOde%k(1,:) = (/5.0, 0.0/)
msdOde%k(2,:) = (/0.0, 9.0/)

msdOde%c(1,:) = (/0.2, 0.0/)
msdOde%c(2,:) = (/0.0, 0.3/)

msdOde%F = (/1.0, 1.0/)
msdOde%omega = (/2.*PI*1., 2.*PI*2./)

y0 = (/0.2, 0.2, 0.0, 0.0/)

! --- do stuff ---
call odeIntEuler(msdOde, t, tEnd, dt, y0)

! =====================
contains

!>
!! Performs simple Euler time integration with a fixed time step.
!<
!=====================================================================
subroutine odeIntEuler(ode, t, tEnd, dt, y0)
!=====================================================================
    type(odeType), intent(in) :: ode

    real*16, intent(in) :: tEnd, dt
    real*16, intent(inout) :: t
    real*16, dimension(nDof*2), intent(in) :: y0

    real*16, dimension(nDof*2) :: y, yDot

    y = y0

    print *, "time,y0,y1,ydot0,ydot1,yddot0,yddot1"
    do while (t<tEnd)

        call ode%derivs(yDot, y, t)

        print "(1x,f0.6,6(',',f0.6))", t, y(1), y(2), y(3), y(4), yDot(3), yDot(4)

        y = y + yDot*dt
        t = t+dt
    enddo

end subroutine odeIntEuler

end program integrationTest
```

Comment: Please provide an example as close to compilable as possible.  And also it would help if you could explain why you "don't seem to be able to declare a separate interface".  What messages does your compiler give when you try, or what do you need to know to be able to try>

Comment: For one thing, you say `derivs => msdDderivs_` but your subroutine is called `msdDerivs_`.

Comment: Oh man, how did I not see that, many thanks! It still doesn't work but for other issues but those I should be able to deal with.

Comment: Basically it seems I cannot define an argument of an abstract type the Euler integration routine to make it accept all derived types, as was my intention.

Comment: For the abstract type you can't have `type(odeType)` but you can have `class(odeType)`.

Comment: As said by @francescalus, you declare the passed variable as `class(odeType)` and it will also accept any DT that `extends` that type.

Comment: Be aware that real*16 is not and has never been part of standard Fortran. The kind mechanism introduced over a quarter of a century ago is both standard and more flexible; I suggest you use it.

Comment: Hi, thank you all for the very useful comments. I've changed the function declaration to include "class" instead of "type" and it works like a charm. And thanks for pointing out the real*16 issue. The framework I recently started working in has its own types and I changed the snippet here to make it more transparent. I'll definitely stick with kind declarations from now on.